# Is it possible to choose which build on test flight you want to use?

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

I have various groups for test flight:
1) Internal Testers
2) Employees
3) Beta Testers

We first distribute to all devs via `Internal Testers`, once we believe it is stable enough, we release to the entire company for further testing and notes, which is `Employees`, and finally we release to all of our `Beta Testers`.

It would be very nice however, to be able to alternate between versions, e.g. say the latest version `7`, which is for `Internal Testers`, fixed a lot of bugs, e.g. validations, but unknowingly, version `6` is broken for `Employees` and `Beta Testers`. Is it possible, if you are part of the `Internal Testers` that are testing version `7`, to revert/test version `6` and see if these changes had any breaking changes?

Comment: yes you can use old build for testing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, in the TestFlight App, tap on the app icon and then select "Previous Builds".

You will then see a list of previous versions  that you have been given access to test. Select the relevant version and then select "install" next to the build of that version that you wish to install.

If you have a known "bad build" you can expire it from the TestFlight page in AppStoreConnect to prevent it from being re-installed.